# Using JQuery, how do I target an element with a style attribute in IE?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors, target

With JQuery, I am targeting the following:

```
<li style="margin-left: 15px;">blah<li>
```

with this code:

```
$(".block-category-navigation li[style='margin-left: 15px;']").addClass('sub-menu');
```

It works great in firefox, but doesn't work at all in IE. Does IE ignore the style selector? Anyway around if so

Comment: If you have a lot of list with "style=margin-left: 15px;" I would put that in a class, e.g., class="margin_left", then you do this $('li').hasClass('margin_left').addClass('sub-menu');

Comment: I can't, using a terrible CMS, thus the akward approach i am using....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking this in IE8's console, I found that it's turning 'margin-left' into 'MARGIN-LEFT'.

In IE this selector will work:

```
$(".block-category-navigation li[style='MARGIN-LEFT: 15px']").addClass('sub-menu');
```

You could either have both upper & lower case selectors, or use a loop to check the style attribute like so:

```
$('.block-category-navigation li[style]').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.attr('style').match(/margin-left: 15px/i)) {
        $this.addClass('sub-menu');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Since I don't want to give you code that doesn't work, I've setup this working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/YB7uV/6/

Comment: my style was "float: left" and I tried with all kinds of caps and spaces but with no luck, but your each function did the trick. thanks. and i thought jQuery was supposed to fix this for us ;(

Answer (score 3):

You can use the marginLeft css attribute with the each() method...not sure if there's a better way though

```
$(".block-category-navigation li[style]").each(function(){
 if($(this).css("marginLeft") == '15px')
    $(this).addClass("myclass");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the code including the `ul` tag as well as the stylesheets that use all of the styles. It is likely in the way you handle your CSS, not with jQuery. I will say that your hyphen use is cause for concern, though as I said before, without the full picture it's difficult to diagnose. Since you're adding a class with a hyphen in the name, jQuery is could be referencing that class as a property rather than a string. Firefox is a bit more graceful in handling Javascript so IE might simply ignore the class addition if the naming is off. You could also try changing that class from `sub-menu` to `submenu` and just see if IE plays along better.